# Manage users in firebase

Tags: firebase

Is it recommended to manage users in the client side or in the server side?
I'm worried about the authentication that has to be done in the client side if I manage the users in the client side.

Comment: There is no recommendation for this as it solely depends on your use case. Users can sign up in our app, use the app etc and we have a Admin app that helps us to manage users. Your use case may be totally different. If you could provide more details it would enable better/more thorough answers. Also, please review [What not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as it will help you write questions that won't be closed for being off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should manage user data on the server. Firebase already provides facilities for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users

Answer (score 0):

I run at the same problem it seems that Java server side API in firebase-admin JAR lacks these methods.

Red line in documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users confirms that :(